# Периодический перенос данных из одной БД в другую

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

Есть две базы. Удаленная PostgresSQL и моя локальная MySQL. Доступ у меня есть. По сути там лежат данные epg
Задача периодически копировать все данные из удаленной таблицы к себе в mysql.
Как логически правильней это сделать и затратить минимум ресурсов и времени!? Данных достаточно много, на данный момент 177000 строк.
Склонен сделать на php, т.к. в нем есть опыт небольшой. На сервере уже стоит драйвер pgsql. Но рассмотрю варианты и на других языках. Запуск планирую по cron, раз в день.

Comment: Вариант реализации: на постгрессе выгрузить в CSV, закачать, импортировать.

Comment: INSERT INTO dbname.tablename(fields...);
SELECT * FROM olddatabase.oldtable;

Comment: @Bloom Счас он спросит, кого, к кому и как подключать...

Comment: пусть спрашивает)

Comment: А поставить локально postgres и настроить репликацию не?